# Athena equivalent for Presto's find_first_index on array column

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

> find_first_index(array(E), function(T, boolean)) → BIGINT#
>
> Returns the index of the first element of array which returns true for function(T,boolean).
> Returns NULL if no such element exists.

This documented presto function does not exist in AWS athena. Is there a good alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Athena is based either on Presto 0.217 (v.2 engine - [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions.html#functions-env2)) or Trino (v.3 engine - [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions.html#functions-env3)) and `find_first_index` was introduced in [Presto 0.280](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.280.html?highlight=find_first_index), in both cases the `find_first_index` is not available,  but you can somewhat simulate it by combining `array_position` and `transform` (which potentially will be not that effective). Something along these lines:

```
select array_position(
      trasnform(array_col, el -> if(some_condition, 1, 0),
      1
   )) 
from ...
```

or

```
select array_position(
      trasnform(array_col, el -> some_condition)
      true
   )) 
from ...
```